# Inherited form creation within Visual Studio 'Outlook 2013 Add-in' project

Tags: forms, winforms, inheritance, visual-studio-2013, vsto

① In Visual Studio 2013, for 'Windows Form Application' project, user is allowed to create a new form based on an existing Windows Form via the 'Project' menu / 'Add New Item...' command.

After selecting 'Inhereted Form' in the list of 'Windows Forms', the 'Inheritance Picker' dialogue allows user to select component to inherit from.
[image]

② In Visual Studio 2013, for 'Outlook 2013 Add-in' project, user is **NOT** allowed to create a new form based on an existing Windows Form via the 'Project' menu / 'Add New Item...' command.

'Inherited Form' is missing in the list of 'Windows Forms'.
[image]

**Question** : Is there any reason why such a difference exists ? If not, how can inherited form be created within 'Outlok 2013 Add-in' project in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VSTO based add-in is not a standalone application. I don't think that developers create a very sophisticated UI there (standalone forms).

And I believe you can create a new form in Visual Studio and then change its base class (System.Windows.Forms.Form) to the existing one.